# Audio Problems: Related to ReportCrash Continually running and SimulatorTrampoline?

Tags: macos, audio, crash

Every ten seconds or so I get static on my audio with distorted sound.

In Activity Monitor I noticed that ReportCrash was consistently running.

Checking the system log I see a lot of messages like:

```
Feb  1 14:03:14 Steves-MacBook-Pro-4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.mdmclient.5492): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /usr/libexec/mdmclient, error = 108: Invalid path
Feb  1 14:04:10 Steves-MacBook-Pro-4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.08000000-0400-0000-0000-000000000000[76300]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[145]
Feb  1 14:04:13 Steves-MacBook-Pro-4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[10386]): Service exited due to SIGABRT
Feb  1 14:04:13 Steves-MacBook-Pro-4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

To track this down I put in a little ps loop:

`while (true) do ps -aef | grep CoreSimulator | grep -v grep; done;`

This outputs:

```
  501 20410     1   0  2:06PM ??         0:00.05 /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/SimulatorTrampoline.xpc/Contents/MacOS/SimulatorTrampoline
```

Since these are started by the system process, it's not clear how it is started.

From my research, `SimulatorTrampoline` is a service that needs mic access. Could this be causing the audio problems?

Is this a common problem? How do I track down which process is starting SimulatorTrampoline?